# Custom Drawer View on press do function inside the screen

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, react-native

I have a custom drawer view with a couple of buttons inside.
When Im clicking on one button I want it to run a function inside my main screen.
For example: I'm opening the drawer, clicking on `button 1`, and it clears my `data` state.

`CustomDrawer.tsx:`

```
return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.drawer}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        ...
      </View>

      <View style={styles.category}>
        <Text style={styles.categoryTitle}>Actions</Text>
        <Item
          icon="delete-outline"
          label="Delete Selected"
          onPress={() => doSomething()}
        />
        ...
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

I need somehow to import the `doSomething()` from my `HomeScreen` into the `CustomDrawer`

`HomeScreen.tsx`

```
export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Document>([]); // List Data

  function doSomething() {
    setData([]);
  }

  return ...
}
```

So, everytime when I click on `Item` it clears my `data`.